# Can't access from internet device to public ip when using yarn buid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I have a problem with my ReactJS application, I use yarn to build my application in a production state. Then I use the "serve -s build" command to launch my application. I can see it perfectly from a local machine, but from outside my local network the page is only loaded with a blank document, and from my phone I can only see that it loads the background of the page but stays there.

Comment: Please open chrome dev tools and post console and network error.

Comment: See the "Network" tab in developer console. Do you see a red records? Resolve it.